# How do I stay logged into Multiple Sandboxes?

Tags: sandbox

How do I stay logged into Multiple Sandboxes when they're all on the same pod?

I have just started at new position and went through and deleted a number of sandboxes that were years old.

Now I am creating new sandboxes and implementing a process so that my team can keep sandboxes only for as long as they need.

This was all going well until I noticed that all of the sandboxes that I have been creating are all on the same pod CS23... Full, Partial and 3 developer instance thus far. I laughed when the first two were on the same box, cursing my luck as it were... but 5 sandboxes cannot be a coincidence. The trouble lies in that I am willing to use Chrome and Firefox but I refuse to use IE and Safari. Both Chrome and FF switch session when I log into a different sandbox... Which is terrible. It doesn't happen when the sandboxes are on different pods.

Is there a way to login to multiple CSnn  instances at the same time?

Comment: So .. do you really want to know whether it's a policy thing, or do you want us to tell you how to stay logged in to all different sandboxes within the same browser ? (chrome accounts will do that for you)

Comment: Man - If I could fix my browser then... awesome.

Comment: Would be awesome if you could rephrase the question to specify that, so that others with thes same question will be able to find this question and answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Understanding that you're mainly looking for a way to stay logged in to many sandboxes at the same time, chrome is the answer here.

1. Got to your chrome settings ( chrome://settings/ )
2. Under "people" you can add chrome-users, these are not the same as your gmail account which can be used to sign in to chrome.
   [image]
3. You'll be able to switch chrome user per window and have different sessions and history etc per chrome user. You can have them all open at the same time in different windows. Per window you can be logged in to a different salesforce org (prod or sandbox).

[image]

My own setup for instance:
[image]

If you need a quick additional session you can use incognito mode, but you can only use that for a single org. All incognito tabs and windows share the same session.

Comment: Alternatively: Set up My Domain in each sandbox, they're guaranteed to not conflict with each other. No need to mess with browser settings or anything else.